# How to get FQDN of salt-minion on which salt is to be run

Tags: salt-stack, fqdn, salt-cloud

I am trying to salt librenms. When replacing the original librenms config file, I want the ServerName to be FQDN instead of Ip address. network.get_fqdn returns IP address as well.

```
{%- from "librenms/map.jinja" import librenms with context -%}
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /opt/librenms/html/
  ServerName {{ network.get_fqdn }}
```

#      ServerName  {{ grains['ipv4'][0] }}

```
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
  <Directory "/opt/librenms/html/">
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using:

- *grains|['minion_id']*, but it depends on the naming rules of the minions ;
- *grains|['nodename']*, but it will be a short name ;
- a *grains* or *pillar* dedicated key.

I would avoid using:

- *grains['domain']*, which can be empty ;
- *grains['fqdn']*, which depends on the network settings.

Otherwise, and if it matches your needs, you can also try without the *ServerName* setting.

Comment: resolved the issue, with {{ grains['localhost'] }}.{{ grains['domain'] }}